# Help w/ Codeigniter __construct()

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I'm checking if a user is logged in. If they are I want to set some variables that will be available to all my functions in that class here is the code thus far. Calling $logged_in or $user_name from my view results in an undefined variable? Please help :)

```
<?php
class Auth extends Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::Controller();

$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('Auth_model');

  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
  {
  $this->user_name = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
  $this->logged_in = TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
  $this->logged_in = FALSE;
  }
}


function forgot()
{  
$data['title'] = "Forgot Password";
$data['main_content'] = "auth/forgot";

$this->load->view('template', $data);
}

    /* My view file */

    <?php echo $user_name; // results in undefined variables ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have passed `$data` in the view and `$data` does not contain `$user_name`

Just befor loading your view you should do something like below so that these variables are available in the view.

```
$data['user_name'] = $this->user_name;
$data['logged_in'] = $this->logged_in.
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

**Edit :**

Declare `$data` as a global variable ie just before initializing constructor as shown below -

`protected $data;`

Then use `$data` as `$this->data` everywhere so if it is initialized with username in one function then it will be available in all functions too.

Comment: Ok so I get that but than in each one of my function I have to do $data['user_name'] = $this->user_name is there a way I can keep this dry?

Comment: @mdgrech: yes that has to be done. Or you can declare data as a global variable and by doing so the above has to be done only once and it will be available in data in every function. :)

Comment: @mdgrech: Edited my code above to include the change that should be done to make it cleaner.

Comment: you might want to change "global variable" to "member variable," because it's an attribute of the object, not part of the global namespace.  I agree with the approach, but suggesting a global variable made me cringe (even though it's not).

Answer (score 0):

An even easier way to do this in your view, instead of using:

> echo $user_name; // results in undefined variables

use:

> $this->session->userdata('user_name') ? $this->session->userdata('user_name') : '';

In simple terms, the above statement checks if user_name is set in the session, and if it is, it displays the user_name straight from the session, or else displays blank. With this you will need to make sure that the session var user_name is destroyed once the user logs out.